# Creating a Progress Bar that reacts to time

Tags: java

I have created a ProgressBar in java. I can set the value using pb.setValue(i); i being an int
I am having trouble making setting the value of 'i' to increment the value of the progressbar so that within 10 seconds the progressbar would reach 1% to 100% in 10 seconds. How can I do this ? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Haven't ya just posted the same question like 20 mins ago . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256762/progress-bar-that-takes-10-seconds-to-reach-100??. We ask you the same question again, what have u tried ?

Comment: @user1730355 - please do not create a *new* question for the same issue; instead, edit your original question to make it more clear and answer any comments directed towards you, then flag it for re-opening.

Comment: i have made a increment of i++, but that just does it every second and i was trying to figure out if i made it a decimals and cast it as an int but still getting inaccurate readings.

Comment: Double posting a previously closed question, when not adding anything to it isn't appricated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TimerTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JProgressBar ps = new JProgressBar();
    final Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int value = ps.getValue() + 1;
            ps.setValue(value);
        }

    });

    ps.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            if (ps.getValue() == 100) {
                timer.stop();
                frame.dispose();
            }
        }
    });
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.add(ps);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    timer.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Look into the java standard library there are time specific functions such as this code snippet.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
methodToTime();
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long duration = endTime - startTime;
```

You set the end and start time such that it will result in a duration or 10 or 1 section depending how you implement your code.

Comment: `nanoTime` might be a little excessive given the fact that the OP wants to reach 10 seconds, but the concept is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You have any number of choices, here are two.

You could establish a timer that ticks every second until it has ticked 10 times, or you could calculate the amount of time that has passed and generate a progress value based on the time passed over the target time, which will produce a smoother progression...

```
public class ProgressOverTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressOverTime();
    }

    public ProgressOverTime() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                frame.add(new TestPane(), gbc);
                frame.add(new TimeGapPane(), gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private int progress;
        private int target = 10;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            pb = new JProgressBar();
            pb.setMaximum(10);
            add(pb);

            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    progress++;
                    if (progress > target) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    pb.setValue(progress);
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

    }

    public class TimeGapPane extends JPanel {

        private JProgressBar pb;
        private long startTime = -1;
        private int target = 10000;

        public TimeGapPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            pb = new JProgressBar();
            pb.setMaximum(100);
            add(pb);

            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (startTime < 0) {
                        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long ticks = now - startTime;

                    float progress = (float)ticks / (float)target;
                    if (progress >= 1f) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                        progress = 1f;
                    }
                    pb.setValue(Math.round(100f * progress));
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setCoalesce(true);
            timer.start();
        }

    }

}
```